# ¿Cómo construir un data.frame con todas las palabras del idioma Español?

Tags: r

Estoy necesitando construir un `data.frame` con palabras del idioma Español (O al menos un número significativo de estas), la idea es usar las mismas para realizar luego, "limpiezas" de otros `data.frame`, de manera de quitar patrones que no se correspondan con palabras válidas.

Existe un recurso en la RAE que es el [Corpus de Referencia del Español Actual (CREA)](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/crea), es un conjunto de unos 140.000 documentos, compuesto por libros, material de prensa y otros. Por otro lado, en el documento mencionado se habla de un [Informe de formas frecuentes](http://corpus.rae.es/lfrecuencias.html) y particularmente me interesa trabajar con [Lista total de frecuencias](http://corpus.rae.es/frec/CREA_total.zip), que según lo que entiendo, es un listado completo de las palabras de este Corpus ordenadas por frecuencia.

La consulta más concreta es: **¿De que forma puedo incorporar este recurso a un `data.frame`?**, y la otras más general **¿es este un recurso válido para lo que busco?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción moderada es tomar la lista de frecuencias: http://corpus.rae.es/frec/10000_formas.TXT

```
listapalabras <- read.table("http://corpus.rae.es/frec/10000_formas.TXT")
head(listapalabras)
   Orden Frec.absoluta Frec.normalizada
1.    de     9,999,518         65545.55
2.    la     6,277,560         41148.59
3.   que     4,681,839         30688.85
4.    el     4,569,652         29953.48
5.    en     4,234,281         27755.16
6.     y     4,180,279         27401.19
```

El problema que le encuentro a la otra opción es que los corpus contienen muchas palabras incorrectamente escritas, con errores de tipeo y se vuelve entonces inútil el data frame como fuente de contraste. Ya en estas diez mil es fácil encontrar palabras que no lo son o que están mal escritas.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a la pregunta más general **¿es este un recurso válido?**, según [esta nota](https://elpais.com/diario/2010/11/27/babelia/1290820336_850215.html), el diccionario de la rae contiene 88.000 términos y el de americanismos unos 70.000, en total, casi un 160.000 términos y según lo que se dice, se suele estimar un 30% más de palabras, es decir que estaríamos hablando que el español posee unas 210.000 palabras. En [enlace](http://corpus.rae.es/frec/CREA_total.zip) comentado, es un archivo comprimido que contiene otro de texto donde cada línea es una palabra y contiene unas 737,799 palabras en total, unas 3 veces más de nuestro numero de base. Hay que tener en cuenta que este recurso contiene todo tipo de conjugaciones verbales. Por lo cual yo diría. en principio, **si, parece un recurso válido y consistente con la idea de tener una lista lo más completa posible, de palabras del idioma Español**.

Lo siguiente es ver como importar este archivo, y transformarlo en un `data.frame`. La siguiente puede ser una manera:

```
tmppath <- tempdir()
tmpfile <- file.path(tmppath,"CREA_total.zip")
url <- "http://corpus.rae.es/frec/CREA_total.zip"
download.file(url, tmpfile)
unzip(tmpfile, exdir = tmppath)
RAE_words <- read.table(file=file.path(tmppath,"CREA_total.TXT"), 
                          sep = "\t",
                          quote = "",
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                          nrows = -1,
                          skip = 1,
                          dec = '.',
                          strip.white = TRUE,
                          fileEncoding = "Latin1",
                          col.names =c("X", "token", "Freq.A", "Freq.N")
                 )

# Estructura del data.frame
str(RAE_words)

'data.frame':   737799 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ X     : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ token : chr  "de" "la" "que" "el" ...
 $ Freq.A: chr  "9,999,518" "6,277,560" "4,681,839" "4,569,652" ...
 $ Freq.N: num  65546 41149 30689 29953 27755 ...

# Primeros casos
head(RAE_words)

  X token    Freq.A   Freq.N
1 1    de 9,999,518 65545.55
2 2    la 6,277,560 41148.59
3 3   que 4,681,839 30688.85
4 4    el 4,569,652 29953.48
5 5    en 4,234,281 27755.16
6 6     y 4,180,279 27401.19
```